# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css:

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to load css file in HTML template in python Django and getting this error
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css:
I am using Pydev , Eclipse, Django framework.

Comment: dev or production? Do you use Apache?

Comment: yes i am using apache. Its dev.

Comment: I am running into same issue. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `STATIC URL` AND `STATIC_ROOT` values in settings file of django project and then create static folder inside your App folder. Place all your css and js files inside this folder.Now add this tag in your template `{% load static %}` and give location of css like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />`

Example
`STATIC_URL='/static/'
 STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")'
 STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Get_Report','static'),)`